# Get string in square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a string: `head1  [00100 - 00228]`

I need to retrieve the value that is there is square bracket, i.e. `00100 - 00228`

I have used:

```
String a="head1  [00100 - 00228]";    
replaceAll("(\\[.*?\\])", ""))
```

but this has removed square bracket string. Can anyone help me to get the desire output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below code

```
String a  = "head1 [00100 - 00228]";
String out = a.substring(a.indexOf("[")+1,a.indexOf("]"));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- escape the square brackets
- use any character for your text and a quantifier
- use lookarounds.

For instance:

```
String input = "head1 [00100 - 00228]";
//                           | follows by "["
//                           |       | any text, reluctant quantifier
//                           |       |  | followed by "]"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
// iterating over all matches, in case input String contains more 
// than one [...] entity
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: 00100 - 00228
```

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was using substring if you know the length of the string before the bracket. But then I thought of Tokenizer. It breaks the string into tokens and you can check each one to see if it starts with the bracket.

Here's a link to the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is what you want

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String s = "head1  [00100 - 00228]";
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(\\[.*?\\]).*");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
      if(m.matches()){
          System.out.println(m.group(1));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using a matcher - you can find multiple parts of a string which match:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MatchingExample {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MatchingExample.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Pattern is: look for square bracket, start capture, look for at least one non-],
    // end capture, look for closing square bracket.
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)\\]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("This is a [string] of [interest]");
    while (m.find()) {
      logger.info("We found: " + m.group(1));
    }
  }

}
```

This will print:

```
We found: string
We found: interest
```